# How to apply a condition in php on big ajax response?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am doing ajax code, and I want the response to put sometimes in one div and other times in an other div on different responses, 
if I have a simple response like,

```
if(xhr.responseText='green'){
  //div1 sould change
}elseif(xhr.responseText='red'){
  //div2 sould change
}
```

but if I am getting a whole div with many elements form php page in responsetext so how I can apply a condition on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
if(xhr.responseText.indexOf("green") != -1){ 
/*do something*/
}
```

to check if the whole div contains word `green` or not you can add unique identified to each different result.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would send JSON from your php code, including a variable to store the text and another that defines what div you should put data into. Something like

```
$object->divname = "div1";
$object->divcontents = ...;
//serialize and send json to the page.
```

In javascript you would deserialize json, decide what div to use and change its contents accordingly. How depends on frameworks you use.

You still can test `responseText` if you send entire contents of div in plain. But you would change the condition depending on what you need to do. For instance, if you need to choose `div1` if the response contains `red`, use `responseText.indexOf("red") != -1`.